# Run multiple Drupal sites from subfolder in root, using multilingual urls

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, drupal-7

I have a (Drupal) website running in a subfolder, with another (Drupal) website running in the root. The website in the subfolder is a multilingual website. I need the subfolder name to change, depending on the language the site is being displayed in, but I'm not able to find or create a working rewrite rule for it.

The scenario is as follows:

The website is located in `folder` with the different languages showing urls like `folder/folder`, `folder/dossier` and `folder/map`. The language tags are handled by Drupal. The end result I desire is:

```
folder/folder >> folder/
folder/map >> map/
folder/dossier >> dossier/
```

This means that the subfolder is removed from the URL, and only the language urls remain.

Any idea how to solve this problem, using htaccess, prefably without redirects, and without having a negative influence on the root website?

Below is the Drupal htaccess being used. The same htaccess is used in the root, but then with the RewriteBase still commented.

---

```
#
# Apache/PHP/Drupal settings:
#

# Protect files and directories from prying eyes.
<FilesMatch "\.(engine|inc|info|install|make|module|profile|test|po|sh|.*sql|theme|tpl(\.php)?|xtmpl)(|~|\.sw[op]|\.bak|\.orig|\.save)?$|^(\..*|Entries.*|Repository|Root|Tag|Template)$|^#.*#$|\.php(~|\.sw[op]|\.bak|\.orig\.save)$">
  Order allow,deny
</FilesMatch>

# Don't show directory listings for URLs which map to a directory.
Options -Indexes

# Follow symbolic links in this directory.
Options +FollowSymLinks

# Make Drupal handle any 404 errors.
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php

# Set the default handler.
DirectoryIndex index.php index.html index.htm

# Override PHP settings that cannot be changed at runtime. See
# sites/default/default.settings.php and drupal_environment_initialize() in
# includes/bootstrap.inc for settings that can be changed at runtime.

# PHP 5, Apache 1 and 2.
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
  php_flag magic_quotes_gpc                 off
  php_flag magic_quotes_sybase              off
  php_flag register_globals                 off
  php_flag session.auto_start               off
  php_value mbstring.http_input             pass
  php_value mbstring.http_output            pass
  php_flag mbstring.encoding_translation    off
</IfModule>

# Requires mod_expires to be enabled.
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
  # Enable expirations.
  ExpiresActive On

  # Cache all files for 2 weeks after access (A).
  ExpiresDefault A1209600

  <FilesMatch \.php$>
    # Do not allow PHP scripts to be cached unless they explicitly send cache
    # headers themselves. Otherwise all scripts would have to overwrite the
    # headers set by mod_expires if they want another caching behavior. This may
    # fail if an error occurs early in the bootstrap process, and it may cause
    # problems if a non-Drupal PHP file is installed in a subdirectory.
    ExpiresActive Off
  </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>

# Various rewrite rules.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on

  # Set "protossl" to "s" if we were accessed via https://.  This is used later
  # if you enable "www." stripping or enforcement, in order to ensure that
  # you don't bounce between http and https.
  RewriteRule ^ - [E=protossl]
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
  RewriteRule ^ - [E=protossl:s]

  # Block access to "hidden" directories whose names begin with a period. This
  # includes directories used by version control systems such as Subversion or
  # Git to store control files. Files whose names begin with a period, as well
  # as the control files used by CVS, are protected by the FilesMatch directive
  # above.
  #
  # NOTE: This only works when mod_rewrite is loaded. Without mod_rewrite, it is
  # not possible to block access to entire directories from .htaccess, because
  # <DirectoryMatch> is not allowed here.
  #
  # If you do not have mod_rewrite installed, you should remove these
  # directories from your webroot or otherwise protect them from being
  # downloaded.
  RewriteRule "(^|/)\." - [F]

  # If your site can be accessed both with and without the 'www.' prefix, you
  # can use one of the following settings to redirect users to your preferred
  # URL, either WITH or WITHOUT the 'www.' prefix. Choose ONLY one option:
  #
  # To redirect all users to access the site WITH the 'www.' prefix,
  # (http://example.com/... will be redirected to http://www.example.com/...)
  # uncomment the following:
  # RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} .
  # RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
  # RewriteRule ^ http%{ENV:protossl}://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
  #
  # To redirect all users to access the site WITHOUT the 'www.' prefix,
  # (http://www.example.com/... will be redirected to http://example.com/...)
  # uncomment the following:
  # RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
  # RewriteRule ^ http%{ENV:protossl}://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

  # Modify the RewriteBase if you are using Drupal in a subdirectory or in a
  # VirtualDocumentRoot and the rewrite rules are not working properly.
  # For example if your site is at http://example.com/drupal uncomment and
  # modify the following line:
  # RewriteBase /drupal
  #
  # If your site is running in a VirtualDocumentRoot at http://example.com/,
  # uncomment the following line:
   RewriteBase /folder/

  # Pass all requests not referring directly to files in the filesystem to
  # index.php. Clean URLs are handled in drupal_environment_initialize().
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
  RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

  # Rules to correctly serve gzip compressed CSS and JS files.
  # Requires both mod_rewrite and mod_headers to be enabled.
  <IfModule mod_headers.c>
    # Serve gzip compressed CSS files if they exist and the client accepts gzip.
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-encoding} gzip
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.gz -s
    RewriteRule ^(.*)\.css $1\.css\.gz [QSA]

    # Serve gzip compressed JS files if they exist and the client accepts gzip.
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-encoding} gzip
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.gz -s
    RewriteRule ^(.*)\.js $1\.js\.gz [QSA]

    # Serve correct content types, and prevent mod_deflate double gzip.
    RewriteRule \.css\.gz$ - [T=text/css,E=no-gzip:1]
    RewriteRule \.js\.gz$ - [T=text/javascript,E=no-gzip:1]

    <FilesMatch "(\.js\.gz|\.css\.gz)$">
      # Serve correct encoding type.
      Header set Content-Encoding gzip
      # Force proxies to cache gzipped & non-gzipped css/js files separately.
      Header append Vary Accept-Encoding
    </FilesMatch>
  </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1):

**1 - Use this rule in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file as first rule:**

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule ^(map|dossier)(/|$) /folder%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC]
```

**2 - Use this rule in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/folder/.htaccess` file as first rule:**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /folder/

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule !^(map|dossier|folder)(/|$) folder%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC]
```

Comment: This helps on root level. However, Drupal is handling the incoming url's, and rewrites them again. I'll accept your answer when I've solved that problem, but I might ask a follow-up question, if I find a good way to formulate the problem. Thanks for now.

Comment: Sure feel free to leave your question in comment section here.

Comment: I edited the question, since my original question didn't solve my problem. Thank you for your time though.

Comment: OK give me some time as I am on mobile now. I will edit the answer as soon as I get back to my computer.

Comment: To understand it better. Somebody will enter `http://domain.com/map/anything` in the browser and you want to silently rewrite that to `http://domain.com/folder/map/anything`?

Comment: That is exactly what I intend to do. And that should work for http://domain.com/map/anything, as well as for http://domain.com/folder/anything and http://domain.com/dossier/anything, while leaving all other URL's intact (to keep the other domain functioning)

Comment: The RewriteRule in the folder/.htaccess generates a 500 error, when placing it at the top of the page. Any clue why that is happening?

Comment: Thanks again for your time. However, it still generates a 500 error.

Comment: Is `http://domain.com/folder/anything` causing 500? Can you also try: `http://domain.com/map/something`

Comment: Everything in the subfolder is creating a 500 error. I think that due to the rewriterule in the root, it will always end up at the same point, from where it creates the 500 error.

Comment: Can you check your Apace error.log and tell me what you see there when 500 happens.

Comment: The error is: [Wed Nov 27 18:00:13 2013] [error] [client 62.207.0.236] Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace. So it seems to be in a loop.

Comment: Still no luck. Now it gives folder/folder, while none of the called files are working, since those are also called at folder/folder. Since I'm starting to feel bad about taking up so much of your time, I would like to thank you kindly, and I will start looking for a different solution.

Comment: Hmm so bad we couldn't reach to a working solution. I have used these exact rules for multi-site setup many times but I guess what makes this different is presence of Drupal in both directories.

Comment: I think so too. That, and my limited knowledge of htaccess I guess. I would like to thank you for the amount of effort and time you put into this.